# How can I merge or concatenate two or more MP4 files creating another MP4 file?

Tags: mp4, merge

How can I concatenate or merge 2 or more MP4 files, in a final output MP4 file also?

I have tried in the DOS window to use the COPY command (I have read it somewhere) but it doesn't function well.

Comment: Also see http://superuser.com/questions/43588/how-can-i-merge-two-mp4-files-without-losing-quality for more information.  Not sure if I would classify this question as a duplicate though.

Comment: kindly add your OS as a tag.

Answer (score 12):

MP4Box can do this, though you might want to use a GUI for it like [YAMB](http://yamb.unite-video.com/) or [My MP4Box GUI](http://my-mp4box-gui.zymichost.com/).  (N.B.: It's not ***my*** program personally, that's just the name.)  MP4Box binaries for Windows are available from [this site](http://kurtnoise.free.fr/mp4tools/).

Example:

```
MP4Box -tmp $HOME -add vid.01.m4v \
    -cat vid.02.m4v -cat vid.03.m4v vid-out.mp4
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd reccomend usind [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html), which is available for Mac OS X, Linux and [Windows](http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/autobuilds/).

Here's a good examaple on how to concatenate two movies:
http://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html#SEC27

In the last step, you just need to make sure you make an MP4 container, for the resulting file.

Comment: As I understand the ffmpeg FAQ answer given, this cannot be done with MP4 (presumably H.264) video, because it's not one of the "privileged formats".

Comment: @ttarchala: I'd try if it can be done. I've converted into MP4 with FFmpeg before, but never concatenated two movies. Also: I'd like to point out, that FFmpeg has a very fast developement. What didn't work with one version, might work in just the next one.

Comment: Not *all* builds of FFMPEG have MP4 support. For one thing it's a patented technology and arguably it's illegal to distribute MP4 encoders in the USA without paying a fee. However, many builds can do this.

Comment: @CarlF: As for Linux and Mac OS X, this is not an issue, really. The code *can* be distributed freely, so basically, whoever builds their own FFmpeg, all is good. As for patenting, I'd like to share a comment: I won't find the site off hand right now, but the first patent to expire for AAC (which is partially defined in MPEG-4), is in 2022. And that's just the first one, there's many more that need to expire till it's completely legal...

Answer (score 4):

You can try doing this with ffmpeg:

```
mkfifo temp0 temp1
ffmpeg -i input0.mp4 -c copy -bsf h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts -y temp0 2> /dev/null & \
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -c copy -bsf h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts -y temp1 2> /dev/null & \
ffmpeg -f mpegts -i "concat:temp0|temp1" -c copy -absf aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```

This doesn't re-encode anything, it places them in a new transport stream container, which makes them more easy to concatenate, and then concatenates them back into an MP4. If output.mp4 already exists, the command will fail. The version above uses named pipes, it you're on a system that doesn't support those you'd have to use intermediate files:

```
ffmpeg -i input0.mp4 -c copy -bsf h264_mp4toannexb temp0.ts
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -c copy -bsf h264_mp4toannexb temp1.ts
ffmpeg -i "concat:temp0.ts|temp1.ts" -c copy -absf aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```

Comment: what if it's not h264 but mpeg4?

Answer (score 2):

Update:
Just checked avidemux as I had it installed, after reading that other answer.
It’s what you are looking for (didn’t think it can do MP4 because of its name…).

I think VirtualDubMod is mp4-capable, I didn’t use it though so I dunno for sure.

You may want to check out [MeGUI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/megui).
It’s a rather complex and feature-rich app and tools.

The tool for embedding in a container (mp4 in your case) is called muxer, that one can probably not concatenate them though.

You can use it in combination with VirtualDub. Virtualdub to concatenate the video streams, and the muxer to make it an mp4 again (without having to reencode).

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing it with mencoder, after having converted them to avi with ffmpeg

here's a simple script, assuming you have 15 files, named 01.mp4 ... 15.mp4

```
#!/bin/bash
for j in `seq -w 1 15`;
do
    echo converting file $j.avi
    ffmpeg -i $j.mp4 $j.avi        

    echo adding file $j.avi to list
    z="$z $j.avi"
done 

echo doing append
mencoder -oac copy -ovc copy $z -o all.avi
```

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Here is the command:

```
ffmpeg -i concat:"video1.ts|video2.ts"
```

Comment: Does that pipe character need to be escaped?  Or am I completely misreading that command?

Comment: it needed to be escaped. oops.