# Concatenate two mp4 videos into one file

Tags: video, mp4, merge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I merge or concatenate two or more MP4 files  creating another MP4 file?](https://superuser.com/questions/173300/how-can-i-merge-or-concatenate-two-or-more-mp4-files-creating-another-mp4-file)

I recently ripped my DVD collection to play them on my media center PC, and several of them are two-disc movies (i.e. The Lord of the Rings).  Since I ripped each DVD individually, that gives me two video files for some movies.

I am using Ubuntu Linux - how can I concatenate these two MP4/H.264 videos into a single MP4 video file?  Preferably from the command line, and without re-encoding everything during the process (although I can try figuring out a video editor like Pitivi if that's the only solution.)

Comment: Possible dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/173300/how-can-i-merge-or-concatenate-two-or-more-mp4-files-creating-another-mp4-file

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this.

1. Using Mencoder

```
mencoder file1.mp4 file2.mp4 -ovc copy -oac copy -of lavf format=mp4 -o output.mp4
```

2. MP4Box

```
MP4Box -add file1.mp4 -cat file2.mp4 output.mp4
```

Note the use of '-add' for the first file and '-cat' for second file; if you mistakenly use '-add' for the second file - you will lose the first file's content.

Comment: I had to tweak these to get it to work: 1) mencoder can't use "-oac copy" on AAC streams for whatever reason; I have to tell it to re-encode on the fly.  2) I ended up using MP4Box, but the example provided overlays the two video and audio streams.  The following command works (use -cat instead of -add for second file):  "MP4Box -add file1.mp4 -cat file2.mp4 output.mp4"  In the end it made the audio out of sync though, so I still have no good solution.

Comment: I agree with @Jer, using the -add option multiple times adds multiple tracks - it does not create an appended video.

Comment: I have edited the post to change the second '-add' to '-cat' based on the comments by Jer above - after testing both options and confirming the comment was correct. (I wasn't able to test the audio option - since my files lacked an audio track)

Comment: I was getting `File not found: 'format=mp4'`. I've had to remove the `format=mp4` section (for mencoder).

Answer (score 1):

Hunt down or build mp4box for your system. It's cli. I don't know of any linux guis for it, but I'm sure some exist.

Install MP4Box

```
sudo apt install gpac
```