# Concatenate .mp4 videos of different encoding parameters using avconv without losing quality?

Tags: libav

How can I use the `avconv` tool to concatenate multiple .mp4 videos of different encoding parameters in a single container, without losing quality?

Comment: You can only do that if the output video is losslessly encoded. Is that acceptable? What's your use case here?

Comment: @slhck Yes, the output video can be losslessly encoded. The use case is that I have different scenes of a movie in separate files, encoded with different parameters. I would like to concatenate them in a single output file, in such a way that each scene retains original quality.

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/a/522658/91054, however that uses `ffmpeg`, and some options are not recognized by `avconv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands [given here](https://superuser.com/a/522658/91054) will not work when videos have different encoding parameters. In fact, you can only concatenate them by bringing them to the same parameters first, working in the decoded (pixel) domain, and then losslessly storing them.

For example, harmonizing the framerate and video dimensions, audio sampling rate and audio channels:

```
avconv -i input_1.mp4 -s 1920x1080 -r 25 -c:v ffv1 -c:a pcm_s16le -ac 2 -ar 44100 out_1.avi
avconv -i input_2.mp4 -s 1920x1080 -r 25 -c:v ffv1 -c:a pcm_s16le -ac 2 -ar 44100 out_2.avi
avconv -i "concat:out_1.mp4|out_1.mp4" -c copy output.avi
```

This uses `ffv1` as lossless codec, but any other lossless codec would work fine (e.g., `huffyuv` in an AVI or `libx264` with `-crf 0` in an MP4).

If you want a "small" output file again, you have no other choice than compressing `output.avi` with some lossy encoder.